# What is this strange floater containing what appears to be links?

Tags: safari, ipados

I browse some sites on my iPad in safari when I first saw this. It stayed on the screen after exiting Safari. I can't seem to kill it, but I can move it around.  [image]

What's this strange floater containing what appears to be links?

Comment: Since you tagged this iPad OS and windows - can you let us know which versions of OS and which versions of safari (and extensions enabled) you’ve had this arrive on? Also - what URL did you use to summon that item?

Comment: Sorry about that.  It was safari for iPadOS, not Windows.

Comment: What happens when you lock the screen? It looks like a multiple tap, tab drag and drop item. How did you manage to get that photo of the items?